# Detecting mouse click on the node of polygone

Tags: c#, winforms, polygon, system.drawing

I am creating a WindowsForms application. In this application I need to draw polygone, using the array with coordinates of polygone's vertexes(nodes).

When user click on one of polygone's nodes, I need to detect, which node is chosen, to suggest user to delete this node.

I am using WindowsForms, PictureBox and Graphics.DrawPolygon for drowing polygones.

How can I detect, if user have clicked on one of nodes? Are there more suitable ways to draw polygones, than WindowsForm and PictureBox?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to check when the picturebox is clicked by running through the nodes points and testing if they are where the user has clicked.

```
Point[] listOfNodes = new Point[1];
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Point item in listOfNodes)
    {
        if (item == e.Location)
        {
            //The node was clicked.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. I agree with this Idea, and also I was hoping that ther is some kind of already-made control, that can be used to draw polygones and had event like polygone_SelectNode. Probably I will have to do it by myself:)

Comment: try google search for a control. but i dont think you would find much.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [X/Y Coordinates of Click on an Image in a Windows Forms Application (.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975468/x-y-coordinates-of-click-on-an-image-in-a-windows-forms-application-net)

You need to get the coordinates and then hit test against your polygon.