# How do I control the circle on C# forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem on C# forms application. I want to make a dart game. The cursor is ok. It will be moving automatically, when you click on form it will "shoot" the form. But I can't calculate the score. How can I find where the background image was shot? By the way, the arrow is a label and I creating that thing when you click on the form. My form size: 500x500 and circles distance 70px.

There is my target detect codes...

```
            if (asama == 0)
        {
            lblNisan.Top = -30;
            asama = 1;
        }
        else if (asama == 1)
        {
            asama = 2;
            Label ok = new Label();
            ok.BackColor = Color.Red;
            ok.AutoSize = false;
            ok.Width = 5;
            ok.Height = 5;
            int a = lblNisan.Left + lblNisan.Size.Width / 2;
            int b = lblNisan.Top + lblNisan.Size.Height / 2;
            if (yon == 0)
            {
                a -= ruzgar;
            }
            else if (yon == 1)
            {
                a += ruzgar;
            }
            else if (yon == 2)
            {
                b -= ruzgar;
            }
            else if (yon == 3)
            {
                b += ruzgar;
            }
            Point yer = new Point(a, b);
            ok.Location = yer;
            this.Controls.Add(ok);
            lblNisan.Visible = false;
            tmrNisan.Stop();

        }
        else if (asama == 2)
        {
            asama = 0;
            tmrNisan.Start();
            lblNisan.Left = -30;
            lblNisan.Top = 185;
            lblNisan.Visible = true;
            ruzgarHesapla();
        }
```

There is my target movements

```
if (asama == 0)
        {
            if (lblNisan.Left <= 430 && yonler == 0)
            {
                if (lblNisan.Left >= 420)
                {
                    yonler = 1;
                }
                else
                    lblNisan.Left += 15;

            }
            if (lblNisan.Left >= -30 && yonler == 1)
            {
                if (lblNisan.Left <= -20)
                {
                    yonler = 0;
                }
                else
                    lblNisan.Left -= 15;

            }
        }
        if (asama == 1)
        {
            if (lblNisan.Top <= 430 && yonler == 0)
            {
                if (lblNisan.Top >= 420)
                {
                    yonler = 1;
                }
                else
                    lblNisan.Top += 15;

            }
            if (lblNisan.Top >= -30 && yonler == 1)
            {
                if (lblNisan.Top <= -20)
                {
                    yonler = 0;
                }
                else
                    lblNisan.Top -= 15;

            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You should post the code you used to draw the circles - that will help us work out which areas of te form need to be triggered to add a score

Comment: So,the background is a image?

Comment: Yes that is backgrıund image

Comment: I don't draw the circles it's a image i want to learn how can i control darts are which in these circles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, a label moves horizontally, then when the user clicks its 'X' position should be saved. After that, it moves vertically, same operation to save its 'Y' position.

And when we have both X and Y, we check the score.

My solution would simply to create two variable to save X and Y in your form (let's call them `currentX` and `currentY`), set them originally at -1, and then use them directly to check at which step you are. The rest is basically the same.

*If you get both X and Y on a single click, just remove the check for currentX == -1 and the return.*

```
private int currentX = -1;
private int currentY = -1;

//...

void myForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (currentX == -1) // remove
    {                   // remove
        currentX = myLabel.Location.X;
        return;         // remove
    }                   // remove

    currentY = myLabel.Location.Y;

    int centerX = this.X / 2.0;
    int centerY = this.Y / 2.0;

    // we'll assume the form is a perfect square, else
    // it gets a bit too complicated
    double bandWidth = /* comcast ? 0 : */ this.Width / (numberOfBands * 2);

    double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(centerX - currentX, 2) + Math.Pow(centerY - currentY, 2));

    if (distance <= bandWidth * 2) // Eagle-eye!
        score += 10;
    else if (distance <= bandWidth * 3)
        score += 9;
    //etc

    // don't forget to reset
    currentX = -1;
    currentY = -1;
}
```

---

*Original answer:*

Without more information, I'll assume you're using an Image for the board. To get the X/Y coordinates of a mouse click on an Image, you can use this solution:

```
this.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(myForm_MouseClick);

void myForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int myX = e.X;
    int myY = e.Y;
}
```

From there, it's trivial to get the distance from your label to your mouse click, using the distance formula:

```
double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(myX - labelX, 2) + Math.Pow(myY - labelY, 2));
```

You should consider using a value relative to the size of your window/form, that you'd divide by the number of bands * 2 (since each band is a circle, it takes 2 different spaces in a given dimension).

```
double bandWidth = this.Width / (numberOfBands * 2);
if (distance <= bandWidth * 2) // Eagle-eye!
    score += 10;
else if (distance <= bandWidth * 3)
    score += 9;
//etc
```

---

References:
 - [Getting the mouse click location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975468/x-y-coordinates-of-click-on-an-image-in-a-windows-forms-application-net)
 - [Distance formula](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/algebra/distance_formula/index.php)

*edit: I totally didn't answer only to make the bandwidth joke.*

Comment: This formula doesn't work because i don't use the mouse X and Y it's only  throw the dart. first click detect X position second click detect Y position and dart will be throw im adding code.

Comment: Can you look at this again i added some codes and details.

Comment: @GökhanGökce Done. The code is not tested, but it should give you the overall idea.

Comment: I'm really thankfull the first one works... I edited for my projects thank you so much =))